# 3 column layout w/ center a vertically centered div

Tags: html, css

here is the structure of my html

```
<style>
  .left {
    float:left;
    width: 450px;
  }
  .center {
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
  }
  .right {
    float:right;
    width:450px;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <a href="javascript:someOnclick();">Add</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>
```

The content of the left div is a table loaded via ajax. What I would like to do is have the link vertically centered (or darn close) dynamically so that when teh table is loaded and that div changes in height my link then moves appropriately. I've created a grid view control on this table and based on the selected value I want to use the link to populate the right column. Any help would be appreciated. The center div has a fixed width but height would probably fill the containing div to allow for vertically centering.

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zbc7R/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>Update
  .left {
    float:left;
    width: 450px;
  }
  .center {
    width: 150px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }
  .right {
    float:right;
    width:450px;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <a href="javascript:someOnclick();">Add</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.D: Don't forget to tick , thanks :D**

Comment: what i really need is the center div to be vertically centered. thanks for the horizontal centering though, that'll help.

Comment: The div or the content of the div?

Comment: A.Quiroga it could really be both, i just want the links to populate the right div to be in the middle of the content of the left div, Vertically that is.

Comment: Sorry but by css , you can't center the container div without using Javascript or absolute position . But text can be done into the div horizontal this way text-align:center;

Comment: yeah, i knew you could do it w/ javascript and thats what i wrote really quick while seeing if a reply that fit my situation came quickly. i haven't had to center vertically over the years very often, but every time i did i remember it made me want to pull my hair out. EDIT: gave you the check because the margin auto bit helped.